# Revoke Instagram Permission Using Api

Tags: php, laravel, instagram-api

i am trying to implement instagram  in laravel
and i am stuck in a point where , i want to revoke instagram permissions, any help will be Great!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hey @Biswajit, i ran into similar situation given documentation is not clear. Did you find something similar for instgram as they have for fb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't revoke the permissions the user granted you via the API. The user can of course revoke, but there is no capability to revoke with the Facebook Graph v13.

Comment: So , you mean to say there isn't any way we can revoke permissions using api ?
I have tried Revoking permissions from facebook , i worked , there is an api available to revoke access in facebook , i am searching the same for instagram @MadsW

Comment: Yes, can't revoke via the API (Facebook Graph API v13). In Facebook you can under Security & Settings.